# Allow staff to edit email data via django admin site?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I would like to give staff the ability to manage the fields from, subject, and body when sending emails without having to edit the html file. Ideally they would be able to do this via the admin site. My thought process is:

1. Create email table with the requested fields
2. Add send_email on admin.py classes when they perform a certain action. When they do, I can get the values for sending emails by getting object from email table based on primary key.

I haven't come across any documentation to set this up and am concerned it's considered bad to do. 
I'm almost certain to be missing something crucial as to why this is a terrible idea... can anyone comment on cases when this would blow up, or that it's odd but shouldn't be an issue? Most of the emails staff edit will be of static text.

Any suggestions/comments/criticism is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [Django DB Templates](http://django-dbtemplates.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for such purpose like email editing in Admin Area.

It's simple and you can save your existing templates to DB templates table.